# Quick fix for splitting a string using regexp

Tags: regex, c#-3.0

I used the following

```
Regex RE = new Regex(@"'?([(\.\//\s\;\,\:\.\)]+)'?");
```

to split the expression which is stored in an xml file.

```
"NIGHT.set('/xs:Service/xs:Location[2]/xs:Res/protocol','HOPR','SP')";
```

It craps out when reading it, because of the single quotes.  I want to get rid of the single quotes in the xml file, changing the expression to,

```
"NIGHT.set(/xs:Service/xs:Location[2]/xs:Res/protocol,HOPR,SP)";
```

but when I try the regexp again, it mostly works, but has a entry in 
split block after applying the regexp of "(\"

So its not doing it right. I'm pretty crap at regexp, so can  anybody quickly 
show me how to change it for the better.

Thanks.
scope_creep

Comment: Are you just trying to get rid of single quotes in the XML file? WHy bother with Regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way you could do it:

```
    string s = "NIGHT.set('/xs:Service/xs:Location[2]/xs:Res/protocol','HOPR','SP')";
    s = s.Replace("'", "");
    Regex re = new Regex(@"^(.*)\((.*)\)$");
    Match match = re.Match(s);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        string function = match.Groups[1].Value;
        string[] parameters = match.Groups[2].Value.Split(',');
        // ...
    }
```

Comment: I need to get the 3 expressions out, plus the NIGHT.set. The expressions drive a set of rule.

Comment: OK, perhaps you should add that info to the question, because it's not at all clear.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [regex coach](http://weitz.de/regex-coach/)? It's a really handy tool for solving these sort of problems.

Comment: I give it a try. I did try regexbuddy, but at the time, didn't have the time to go through it.